# Retrieving ExactTarget user from Journey Builder

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

We've built an app for HubExchange and retrieve the user that has authenticated with the app in the [decoded JWT payload](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/single-sign-on.html#decoded-jwt). This is all fine.

However, with a Custom Activity, Journey Builder uses the Endpoint URL that has been defined in AppCenter (for the Custom Activity) and doesn't use JWT so we don't know which ExactTarget user is interacting with Journey Builder.

Is there a method that we can use to get the current user from Journey Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Postmonger events, "requestTokens" and "requestedTokens" you should be able to pull out this context information.

```
connection.on('requestedTokens', function(tokens) { ... });
```

Comment: @EliotHarper How to find the user from the `tokens` received in the *requestedTokens* function?

Comment: I can't recall, that was a couple of years ago and I don't have access to that code now. But I do remember that we were able to retrieve the user context from this Postmonger event.

Comment: @EliotHarper, I found there is an API to retrieve the `UserContext` using the token. But, do you know any way to get the user context using Postmonger without calling the API?

Comment: @EliotHarper I'm trying to get the current logged in user's email address `requestedTokens` provides just the `userId` any ideas on how to approach? Here is my original question. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249109/marketing-cloud-api-custom-activity-get-current-user-details