# Marketing Cloud API - Custom Activity - Get current user details

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I'm trying to get current logged in user's `emailAddress` and `name` fields within a java app. This java app is embedded in a custom activity in the journey builder. Java app uses [FuelSDK](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/) to retrieve data from Marketing Cloud.

I have followed the approach described in the answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184747/identify-marketing-cloud-account-user-details-journey-builder-custom-activit).

According to that approach, when I hit the `GET /platform/v1/tokenContext` endpoint, [I get this response](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/gettokencontext.htm).

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
{
    "enterprise": {
        "id": 1081365
    },
    "organization": {
        "id": 1081365
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1093240
}
```

But I'm unable to find a way to retrieve other user details such as `emailaddress` and `name` with this `user.id`.

If anyone of you could point me in the right direction, much appreciate your help.

Comment: is the UserId the ContactId ?

Comment: if yes you can create a ContactId field on your population and query you data extension to find details with a lookup using user.id. You can populate this field via  journey using data binding

Comment: @AshBringer unfortunately it's not the `contactId`It's currently logged in users id. But I can't see this id in any of the data extensions within marketing cloud either.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the account's user info with this method
GET YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/userinfo