# Marketing Cloud - retrieve username/email of logged-in users

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to get the list of current Marketing Cloud Users using REST API with [GET YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/userinfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getUserInfo.htm) as shown below.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  try {
    /* get OAuth 2.0 access token */
    var payload = '{"grant_type": "client_credentials",';
    payload += '"client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",';
    payload += '"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",';
    payload += '"scope": null,';
    payload += '"account_id": "xxxxxxxxx"}';
    var OAuth2URL = "https://SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = 'application/json';
    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(OAuth2URL, contentType, payload);
    var tokenObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]);
    var accessToken = tokenObj.access_token;
    var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

    /* make the API call and get the response */
    //var content = [0];
    var urlCreate = "https://SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/userinfo";
    var response = HTTP.Get(urlCreate, contentType, headerNames, headerValues);
    Write(Stringify(response));
  }
  catch(e) {
    Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

However, I am keep getting an error message saying:

> {"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this
>   frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
>   retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

Has anyone ever encounter the same issue?

Basically, what I want to achieve here is to get the list of current active MC users and display their username & email address in the cloudpage.

---

Thanks for looking into this @Gortonington

These is the error message that I am currently getting:

```
{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n ClientID: MID12345\r\n JobID: 0\r\n ListID: 0\r\n BatchID: 0\r\n SubscriberID: 0\r\n URL: https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/accounts/MID12345/users\r\n","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n ClientID: MID12345\r\n JobID: 0\r\n ListID: 0\r\n BatchID: 0\r\n SubscriberID: 0\r\n URL: https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/accounts/MID12345/users\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.OMMException: An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call. URL: https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/accounts/MID12345/users\r\n Error Code: HTTP_WB_RTV\r\n - from OMMCommon --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 2---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first thing of note is that you used the 'auth' endpoint for both (`https://SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com`).  When the 'urlCreate' should be using: `https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com`.

Second, I noticed you added in a 'contentType' parameter to the `HTTP.Get` function, which does not [exist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpGet.htm). This would need to be removed and was a likely culprit for your initial received error. Should be: `HTTP.Get(urlCreate, headerNames, headerValues)`

Thirdly, I have not heard of `v2/userinfo` before and it does not even contain the normal structure that the REST endpoints utilize and the only released v2 endpoint for public consumption is around the Authentication process.

I investigated this endpoint and have found no evidence that it is valid. If you have any evidence or documentation on this, I would be happy to ingest it and further explore there.

BUT to get the end result that you want, there is an endpoint in REST that should provide this: `/platform/v1/accounts/{{mid}}/users`.  This is only for that specific MID declared, but it will give all current user info.

So basically you would want to rewrite your script above to:

```
%%[ SET @mid = [memberid]
]%%

<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  var mid = Variable.GetValue("@mid");

  try {
    /* get OAuth 2.0 access token */
    var payload = '{"grant_type": "client_credentials",';
    payload += '"client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",';
    payload += '"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",';
    payload += '"scope": null,';
    payload += '"account_id": "xxxxxxxxx"}';
    var OAuth2URL = "https://SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = 'application/json';
    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(OAuth2URL, contentType, payload);
    var tokenObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]);
    var accessToken = tokenObj.access_token;
    var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

    /* make the API call and get the response */
    //var content = [0];
    var urlCreate = "https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/accounts/" + mid + "/users";
    var response = HTTP.Get(urlCreate, headerNames, headerValues);
    Write(Stringify(Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content).items));
  }
  catch(e) {
    Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Gortonington , Thanks for the detailed information. I also wasn't sure if v2/userinfo endpoint would give me what I want or not. Thanks once again!

Comment: Apologies to bother you once again, but would you happen to have a document on the /platform/v1/accounts/mid/users endpoint?

It's just that I am now getting an error message saying: 

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n ClientID: MID12345\r\n JobID: 0\r\n ListID: 0\r\n BatchID: 0\r\n SubscriberID: 0\r\n URL: https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/accounts/MID12345/users\r\n","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionE...

Comment: It is undocumented, so there is no documentation available for it. Can you either update your question with the full error for me to better review or add in your current code to it? Also, can you show me where you got the `v2/userinfo` endpoint from? I would love to look more into that if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response once again. :-) I got the idea from on of the posts in the StackExchange: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249109/marketing-cloud-api-custom-activity-get-current-user-details and also there is a documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getUserInfo.htm

Comment: I have also updated my question with the full error message. Thanks,

Comment: @jcloud - Thanks for sharing the docs! Goes to show just because you are an expert in something, doesn't mean you know everything!  Good news is that you can use the v2/userinfo (I got it to work). As for the undocumented one I recommended, you need to remove the `MID` part from the URL. and just put the numbers. `/accounts/MID12345/users` should be `/accounts/12345/users`. If that still fails, I would check the scope on your token request and on the package/application you built in SFMC and ensure you have correct permissions for this.

Comment: BUT - the user info (v2/userinfo) I believe only returns for your specific user (the one associated with the token). not all users. So that may not meet your needs.

Comment: Happy Friday @Gortonington - After reading through your comments, I have a feeling that this error  has got something to do with my API package permission set up! I will review my permission settings later today. Thank you! :-)